# Hyperplane which does not contain any associated point of qc sheaf $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I have a question about an argument on $m$-regularity
from 'Fundamental Algebraic Geometry' by Fantechi on page 114, Chapter
5.2: Castelnovo-Mumford regularity. The statement is:

> Let $k$ be a field and let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on the projective
> space $X:= \mathbb{P}^n$ over $k$. Let
> $m$ be an integer. The sheaf $F$ is said to be $m$-regular if we have

> $$H^i(\mathbb{P}^n,F(m-i))=0 \text{ for each } i \ge 1 $$

recall $F(j):= F \otimes_{O_X} O_X(j)$ is the $j$-the Serre twist.

> The definition, which may look strange at first sight, is suitable
> for making inductive
> arguments on $n = \dim(\mathbb{P}^n)$ by restriction to a
> suitable hyperplane. If $H \subset \mathbb{P}^n$  is a
> hyperplane which does not contain any *associated point* of $F$,
> then we have a short exact sheaf sequence

> $$0 \to F(m-i-1) \to F(m-i) \to F_H(m-i) \to 0$$

QUESTION: Why the assumption that hyperplane $H$
does not contain any *associated point* of $F$, imply that the exact
sequence

$$ 0 \to O_X(m-i-1) \to O_X(m-i) \to O_H(m-i) \to 0 $$

stays exact (especially LEFT exact) after tensor by $F \otimes -$
if we assume $H$ not contain any *associated point* of $F$.

recall the definition:  Let $X$ be a scheme and $F$ be a
quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. We say $x \in X$ is associated to $F$ if the maximal ideal $m_x$
of $O_{X,x}$ is associated to the $O_{X,x}$-module $F_x$, i.e. $m_x=Ann(f)$ for
certain $f \in F_x$.

ADDENDUM: I think the problem is closely related to exercise 20.2A
from Ravi Vakil's
excellent Rising Sea notes (page 542):

Suppose $X$ is a regular projective
surface $X$ and $C$ and $D$ are effective divisors (i.e.,
curves) on $X$.

show (b): If $C$ does *not contain any associated point* of $D$
(so in particular, if $C$ and $D$
have no components in common), show that
(20.2.0.4) $C · D = h^0(C \cap D,O_{C \cap D})$.

Here the strategy looks also similar: start with exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_D \to 0$$

tensor it with $O_C$ and show that

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_C(-D) \to \mathcal{O}_C \to \mathcal{O}_{D \cap C} \to 0$$

is still exact. I think here occure exactly the same story, namely
$D$ is the hyperplane $H$ and $O_C=F$ with $C= Supp(O_C)$. Why in this case
the assumption that $C$ does not contain any associated point of $D$
imply the last sequence stays exact?

Comment: Reduce to the affine case. I think that on an affine open $U$ of $P^n$ you see a sequence of the form $ 0 \rightarrow k[U] \overset{f}{\rightarrow} k[U] \rightarrow k[H\cap U] \rightarrow 0$, where $f$ is not in any associated prime of $M=F(U)$. In particular $f$ is a nonzerodivisor on $M$, so tensoring with $M$ leaves the map injective.

By the way (for others passing by), this part of the text can also be found at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590

Comment: @GevaYashfe: ahh, probably I see the issue. We use here that the set of zerodivisors equals the union of associated primes? This is your argument, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.